# Invariant equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, invariance

If I have the equation:

$x=-$tan$x$

I can send $x \rightarrow -x$ and the equation doesn't change. If I define $x>0$ **one** of the possible ranges $x$ can take **without solving the equation** is

$\pi/2<x<\pi$

because of invariance if $x<0$, one of the possible ranges $x$ can take is:

$-\pi<x<-\pi/2$

However if I were to have an invariant equation in which there was no solution for $x>0$, would that necessarily mean there is no solution to the equation for $x<0$?

Comment: Yes. If there were a solution for $x<0$, then $-x$ would be a positive solution, a contradiction.